# React native file upload using dropzone to flask

Tags: react-native, flask, fetch

Hi I want to upload file using React native to flask server
I sent a file using fetch function and I received response. But print(request.files) result ImmutableMultiDict([]) how to I see my file in server? I checked state was right and I got response {'state' : 'ff'}

react native

```
    pressSumbitButtom() {
        var formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('file', this.state.file)
        return fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/file/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            },
            body: formData
        }).then(res =>
            res.json()
        ).then(data => console.log(data))
    }
```

App.py

```
@app.route("/file/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@cross_origin(origin='*', headers=['Contect-Type'])
def get_filepath() :
    response = jsonify({'state':'ee'})
    if request.method == 'POST' :
        print('response: ',response, 'request: ', request)
        print(request.files)
        response= jsonify({'state':'ff'})
        return response
    return response
```